# Mac Book Air Power Supply voltage range

Tags: mac, macbook, power-supply

I am flying to the US soon (from the UK) and want to know if a Mac Book air from the US will work here considering the voltage difference.

Most laptops have a 'power brick' which works over a range of voltages say, 100V - 240V.

Does anyone know the range of the power supply of a US Mac Book Air.

Answer (score 2):

The excellent [Mactracker](http://www.mactracker.ca/) says a new generation MBA has a 100-240V AC / 45W MagSafe adapter.

All Macs have these Voltage ranges so that one only needs the [Apple Travel Kit](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB974ZM/B) to use them anywhere in the world.

Answer (score 0):

The charger is universal all over the world.

The only thing you need is a $2 socket adapter for the wall outlet for Country you are going.

All over Europe it is the same plug, but I do not know for UK.